# Laravel DB multiple calls on one page

Tags: php, database, laravel

So I have Laravel running and I'm curious how to correctly run multiple queries in one view using Model, Controller, View etc.

Say I have a dashboard like the one below..
http://demos.creative-tim.com/paper-dashboard/dashboard.html?_ga=2.265584009.705745056.1515528943-448113063.1513264324

and i want to run different queries in each box. One of users, payments, etc. I'm just curious how i correctly use routes etc to bring in multiple calls in one view?

So say I have a User count method in the User model and Payment Total method in its model - how do I bring them together in one View (dashboard)?

Comment: get the different query result in different variable .then pass to view using compact or with

Comment: No need for routes, in your controller action you can call different methods from different classes and assign them to your view

Comment: @kerbholz something like this perhaps? 

[code]
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    
  public function index()
  {

    $capacity = Capacity::getCapacity
    $income = Income::getIncome

    $args = array('capacity' => $capacity,
         'income' => $income); 

    return view('dashboard.index',compact($args)); 

  }

}
[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do something like this,

```
  $data = array(
            'res' => $res,
            'currentYearTitle' => Carbon::now()->format('Y'),
            'process' => Process::where('type', 3)->limit(4)->get(),
            'payments' => Payments::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get(),
            'threelastYearTitle' => Carbon::now()->subYears(3)->format('Y'),
            'type' => 'active'
            );
          return view('admin.profile.index', $data);
```

To access the data on the page you would access it by `$res` ... `$process` etc.